# Printing numpy with different position in the column

Tags: python, numpy

I have following numpy array

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(20)
np.random.rand(20).reshape(5, 4)

array([[ 0.5881308 ,  0.89771373,  0.89153073,  0.81583748],
       [ 0.03588959,  0.69175758,  0.37868094,  0.51851095],
       [ 0.65795147,  0.19385022,  0.2723164 ,  0.71860593],
       [ 0.78300361,  0.85032764,  0.77524489,  0.03666431],
       [ 0.11669374,  0.7512807 ,  0.23921822,  0.25480601]])
```

For each column I would like to slice it in positions:

```
position_for_slicing=[0, 3, 4, 4]
```

So I will get following array:

```
array([[ 0.5881308 , 0.85032764,  0.23921822,   0.81583748],
       [ 0.03588959, 0.7512807 ,  0             0],
       [ 0.65795147, 0,           0             0],
       [ 0.78300361, 0,           0             0],
       [ 0.11669374, 0,           0             0]])
```

Is there fast way to do this ? I know I can use to do for loop for each column, but I was wondering if there is more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Please clarify why 0 corresponds to the entire first column, 2 corresponds to the last two elements of the second column, and 1 corresponds to... well, I'm not sure how you used 1 when pulling out the values from the last two columns.

Comment: for first columns its 0, so I  Will keep original column, for the 2nd column is position 2, so I would like to get values at  position 4, 5 and so on

Comment: For the last column, I think you should have `0.2548061`. Also, what if the user enters 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "elegant" means "no loop" the following would qualify, but probably not under many other definitions (`arr` is your input array):

```
m, n = arr.shape
arrf = np.asanyarray(arr, order='F')
padded = np.r_[arrf, np.zeros_like(arrf)]
assert padded.flags['F_CONTIGUOUS']
expnd = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(padded, (m, m+1, n), padded.strides[:1] + padded.strides)
expnd[:, [0,3,4,4], range(4)]
# array([[ 0.5881308 ,  0.85032764,  0.23921822,  0.25480601],
#        [ 0.03588959,  0.7512807 ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
#        [ 0.65795147,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
#        [ 0.78300361,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
#        [ 0.11669374,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Please note that `order='C'` and then `'C_CONTIGUOUS'` in the assertion also works. My hunch is that 'F' could be a bit faster because the indexing then operates on contiguous slices.